# Page break on a RDLC Report Table

Tags: pdf, report, rdlc

I have a Table on a RDLC Report. The number of table's rows increases dinamically according to my dataset.
When I print my report to a PDF document, if the cell's text is too 'big', it prints every table on the next page of the document.
All I need is to break the table whenever it will be necessary.
How can I do that? Any ideas ?
I've tried to set both table and textbox's Keep Together property to False and it dosent's worked  out...

---

SOLUTION:

On the bottom of report designer there are a Row Groups and Column Groups area. I set this are to Advanced Mode. Then, I change every group KeepTogether property to False. After that, I change every Static KeepTogether property to False and KeepInGroup to None.

---

Thank you in advance.

Best regards, 
Maria

Comment: i did that and Rdlc is still breaking the table when exporting to pdf