# Rdlc export to pdf break table

Tags: asp.net, pdf, export, report, rdlc

I am using `RDLC report` which consists of table and looks like this:

[image]

After exporting to `Pdf` table jumps to second page and makes first page almost empty.

[image]

It occurs when table fits right in second page. In situation when there is more data, table starts directly after header.
Is it possible to force table to stay in first page no matter on it size ?

This topic also didnt help 
[Page break on a RDLC Report Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620231/page-break-on-a-rdlc-report-table)

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:asp-classic].  Try registering it under [tag:asp.net] to get some responses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solutions:
Had to select on Report menu "Grouping"
Choose Advanced mode.
Then on Row Groups panel select on table and in property window set "KeepTogether" to false.

[image]

Comment: I tried that and Rdlc is still breaking the table when exporting to pdf